# Cropping portion of last character in right aligned paragraph inside column-text in iText

Tags: itext

I am using column text in composite mode and adding paragraphs to it.
Paragraph has alignment, left or right. The last character of a line when right aligned is cropped partially even when there is enough space on the left for the line of text in this right aligned paragraph. The last character that is cropped has a width smaller than the difference of xmin and xmax of its bounding box. How can stop this cropping? 
Below is an example.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.log.SysoCounter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class CroppingSSCCE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FontFactory.register("MrsEavIta.ttf");


        float llx = 0;
        float lly = 0;
        float urx = 136.93744978164614f;
        float ury = 32.86498794759508f;
        Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);



        try {
            FileOutputStream baos = new FileOutputStream("CroppingSSCCE.pdf");
            Document document = new Document(pageSize);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
            canvas.getPdfDocument().setPageSize(pageSize);

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            Font font = FontFactory.getFont("MrsEavesItalic", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 28, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Hello T", font);
            paragraph.add(chunk);

            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
            ct.setSimpleColumn(pageSize);
            ct.setUseAscender(true);
            ct.addElement(paragraph);
            ct.go();

            document.close();
            writer.close();
            baos.close();
        } catch (Exception de) {
            System.out.print("Error: " + de.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem? I have never see the behavior that you're describing.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have updated above description with example.

Comment: I have tried this example with a different font (I don't have this Mrs Eaves Italic) and I can't reproduce the problem. Maybe the problem is caused by the font. Maybe the `width` of the italic letters is defined in a way that it doesn't match the complete glyph. (The complete glyph is there, but you clip it by reducing the size of your page.)

Comment: I have switched the font to an italic font and I even threw in a glyph with a descender. Indeed: the descender and the italic part is rendered *outside* the visible area of the page (because you define the page to have the exact same dimension of the column). This is a problem inherent to some fonts. It's not something we're going to fix.

Comment: My page is only as big a the column, but the column has enough free space on the left side when I right align, shouldn't 'ColumnText' word wrap and go to next line in case of insufficient space in current row/line but not clip the character. On x-axis/horizontally, goes beyond origin(0,0) and width(width,0) for these italic characters that get chopped off. It looks like iText ignores 'bearings' and 'advances' in the font.

Comment: `ColumnText` is a convenience class that was created to quickly position text at absolute coordinates. If it doesn't meet your needs, you should resort to the low level methods that allow you to position glyph by glyph based on the characteristics of each glyph.

Comment: Thanks, your replies were helpful.